# Windows IoT Dashboard won't 'Sign in' and it's 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

Tags: windows-iot, windows, update

Today IoT Dashboard asked for update (I didn't open it for some months) and I accepted. Now I have these problems and I'm unable to install a new device:

1. When I click *'Sign in'* nothing happen
2. If I try to install a new device said *'Unable to connect to the remote server'*
   [image]

more info:

- PC: Windows 10 Pro 14393.479 with Windows Developer features installed.
- Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard Preview 1.0.1612.1000
- Even after the Dashboard update, it was able to see the RPi in the network, but after I rotated the screen 180 and restarted, the RPi shows a BSOD. Now I need reinstall the SD and I have this problem